# Showing that for all positive integers m and n there are sorted lists with m elements and n elements such that m+n-1 comparisons are needed

Tags: mergesort

I was trying to solve a discrete math question regarding the comparison needed by a merge-sort algorithm. I wanted to ask if there were a more formal way to put organize my reasoning for this problem and if my reasoning were right in the first place.

"Show that for all positive integers m and n there are sorted lists with m elements and n elements, respectively, such that merge-sort algorithm uses m + n − 1 comparisons to merge
them into one sorted list."

Suppose $m = n$. Then let $L1$ be the list of $[ a_{0},a_{1}...a_{m} ] $ and $L2$ the list $ [b_{0},b_{1}...b_{n}  ] $

where for $i$ in  {0,1...m}, $ b_{i} = a_{i} + 1 $, so that for every  $i$ in  {0,1...m}, $ a_{i} = b_{i} - 1 $

And we assume they have no $L1$ and $L2$ have no common elements.

Examples of these kind of lists might be [1,9,11,21],[2,10,12,22].

Now we start considering the comparisons needed:

1. I will need one comparison between $a_{0} $ and $  b_{0}$. T
2. Then $ a_{1}$ will be higher then $b_{0}$ so i will need another comparison.

Now We have done a total of 2 comparison and we have reduced ourself to a case in which we have two lists with $m-1$ = $n-1$ elements that present the same pattern. So two more steps will be needed in order to get two listw with $m-2$ = $n-2$ elements.

So I will need to do a total of $2(m-1)$ comparisons before reaching the case in which I have two list of a single element each : $ [a],[b]$. Then a single comparison before getting an empty list will be needed, and no more comparisons will be necessary to complete the merge sort.

So i will, for these two kind of lists, $2m-2+1 $ comparisons, so $2m - 1 $ comparisons, so, since $m=n$, $m+n -1$ comparisons.

Comment: "such that merge-sort algorithm uses $m + n − 1$": shouldn't it be "merge algorithm" only? There is no sorting involved in your question, only merging.

Comment: Your reasoning seems right but you only consider the case $m=n$. Why don't you just  choose $L_1 = \langle 1, \dots, m-1, \infty \rangle$ and $L_2 = \langle m+1,m+2 ,\dots,m+n \rangle$?

Comment: @Steven Thanks, so your example would be a list in which we make $m$ comparisons for the elements in $L1$, up until $∞$ (but any value higher then $m+n$ would serve the same purpose) and then do $n$ comparisons by comparing $∞$ with all the elements of $L2$